# Simple web server using Flask, doesn't work!

Tags: web-server

Trying to set up my Pi as a web server with flask. It works only sometimes, and then only for about 30 seconds. When I stop the script, it returns this error:

Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.exceptbook is missing
lost sys.stderr

`from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(name)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    templateData = {
        'title':'Hello!
        }
    return render_template('main.html', **templateData)
if name == "main":
    app.run(host='10.0.0.10', port=80, debug=True)`

After it stops working the first time, the Pi must be restarted before it will work again. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you provide full error message (with stacktrace) and tell US show exactly do you run the script?

Comment: Have you tried using the ip already assigned to your PI rather than 10.0.0.10?

Comment: I checked the ip with ifconfig. I ran the script from the command line: sudo python script.py

Comment: It returns: running on http://10.0.0.10, restarting with reloader.  But I cannot access 10.0.0.10 from another computer on the network. The funny thing is it does work sometimes, like 1/10 times

Comment: Here is a self-contained project that uses flask.   Might be useful:  https://hackaday.io/project/9012-pihole-raspberry-pi-text-to-speech-msg-server

Answer (score 1):

The problem was something to do with my router. It worked when I tried it with a different router at a friend's house!

Comment: So what happened when you brought it home?